# Octobercms Backend List Timeout

Tags: php, mysql, apache, octobercms, octobercms-backend

i'm working with backend and having around 100k records in the table. The problem is, when im loading this list, request times out because it takes longer than 30 seconds to load and also if it manages to load (increasing timeout) the list is not separated to pages, just whole list of records on the one page.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue and is there a way to fix this bug?

Comment: Have you got something like `recordsPerPage: 25` in your `config_list.yaml` ? I noticed when using the builder plugin it doesn't add it automatically.

Comment: @Joseph Hello, thank you for fast reply. This line is there, so this is why i've  decided to come here. This was the first thing i've checked

Comment: I can't think what could be causing that on a default setup -- an absence of a db index could make it timeout but not show the whole list like that -- but if you've done anything custom then I guess post the full controller and yaml code and maybe I (or someone else) will notice something.

Comment: @Joseph Thank you for spending time on that, i've decided to disable functionality to view this database table and to create a search page instead so i can go directly to the entry

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may need to enable pagination on your list. Open the `list_config.yaml` configuration file found in your controller directory and check for the `recordsPerPage` option:

```
# ===================================
#  List Behavior Config
# ===================================

# ...

# Records to display per page
recordsPerPage: 20
```